# How to Implement AJAX in Angular 2 through a Javascript Function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, function, angular

I want to implement AJAX in Angular 2, but I don't now how to do this.

I have my Angular 2 component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
declare var filter: any;
declare var pageLoaded: any;

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'Summary',
    templateUrl: '/app/summary-view/summary.component.html',
    styleUrls: [
        './summary.component.css',
    ]
})

export class Summary implements AfterViewInit {

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        pageLoaded();
        filter();
    }

}
```

In a Javascript file I have the function pageLoaded, this function includes an AJAX Call:

```
function pageLoaded() {
    function fillFormattedDates(dates) {
        var optionsd = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
            if (i == 0) {
                optionsd += `<option id=${dates[i]} value=${dates[i]} selected>${formatDate(dates[i])}</option>`;
            } else {
                optionsd += `<option id=${dates[i]} value=${dates[i]}>${formatDate(dates[i])}</option>`;
            }
        }
        document.getElementById('tableDates').innerHTML = optionsd;
    }
    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        url: `http://${host}${port}/api/v1/chart/c3/dates`,
        type: "GET",
        cache: false,
        success: function(dates) {
            fillFormattedDates(dates.data);
            refreshTable();
        }
    });
}
```

How can I implement this AJAX call using Angular 2? I will really appreciate your help.

Comment: use the `http` module? https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html

Answer (score 1):

You should use Angular2 Http client. Official doc - [HTTP CLIENT](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html)